# What dependencies are needed for the golang tool chain?

Tags: docker, go

I'm trying to build a minimal docker image for go using this Dockerfile

```
FROM debian:stretch-slim AS builder                                                                                                   

ENV VERSION 1.9.3.                                                                                                                    
ENV OS linux                                                                                                                          
ENV ARCH amd64                                                                                                                        

RUN apt update && apt upgrade -y && apt install -y curl                                                                               
RUN curl -O -fsSL "https://dl.google.com/go/go$VERSION$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz" \ 
&& tar -C /usr/local -xzf "go$VERSION$OS-$ARCH.tar.gz"        
RUN /usr/local/go/bin/go env                                                                                                          

FROM scratch                                                                                                                          
ENV GOPATH=/code                                                                                                                      
ENV PATH=/usr/local/go/bin                                                                                                            

COPY --from=builder /usr/local/go /usr/local/go                                                                                       
CMD ["/usr/local/go/bin/go"]
```

Building this image using `docker build -t golang:1.9.3 .`. The output of the container is as follows, if executed like this `docker run --rm -ti golang:1.9.3`:

```
standard_init_linux.go:195: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

**EDIT**:
I am aware of the golang images on docker hub like golang:alpine, which is ~265MB in size.

Comment: The Go binary downloads are linked against glibc. If you want a static build, you need to build it from source. You can also look at the alpine dockerfiles directly and see what's required there.

Comment: Good point. I will have a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using this for a build server? If the containers are to run Go applications, Go itself is not a dependency.

Comment: no. it's basically about distributing applications packed in small containers. go itself is truly not a dependency, and can be packed as-is in a bare docker container (eg. scratch). the goal is to have all build tools readily configured.

Comment: So I get it right that, as an end result, you want to build a binary with Go and deploy the resulting application in a minimal image, right?

Comment: Not quite. As I said, deploying a single go binary in a container is no problem at all. What I'm trying to do is to package the development tools (the go compiler) into a small container.